# Why my producer-consumer program in C not working properly?

Tags: c, synchronization, system, semaphore, producer-consumer

I'm trying to synchronize 02 child processes that communicate using a buffer of size 5 using the semaphores "empty" and "full" only.
Process 01 executes **producer()** function and the second one executes **consumer()**, but the consumer functions does not execute at all even when the producer is blocked (empty=0).
after 5 iterations, I only get 5 insertions but no consuming ( I'm inserting 5's for now). Also I believe there is no need for a mutex since there are only 01 producer and 01 consumer right? here are the 02 functions and the main program:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MaxItems 5 
#define BufferSize 5 

sem_t empty;
sem_t full;

//pthread_mutex_t lock;

int in = 0;
int out = 0;
int buffer[BufferSize];
int N = 20;

void *producer()
{   
    while(1)
    {
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        sem_wait(&empty);
    
        buffer[in] = 5; // fill the buffer with numbers
        printf("\nInsert Item %d at %d\n", buffer[in],in);

        int emptyvalue, fullValue;
        sem_getvalue(&full, &fullValue); sem_getvalue(&empty, &emptyvalue);
        printf("full is:%d, empty is:%d\n", fullValue, emptyvalue);

        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);  
        sem_post(&full); // increase the value of full, so the consumer should execute now?
        in = (in+1)%BufferSize;
        usleep(500000);
    } 
}

void *consumer()
{   
    printf("test: consumer"); //this consumer function does not execute
    
    while (1)
    {
        sem_wait(&full); // full initially is = 0, so it blocks at first
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
       
        int item = buffer[out];
        printf("Remove Item %d from %d\n",item, out);
        
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        sem_post(&empty);

        printf(" %d", out); //using the values in the buffer
        out = (out+1)%BufferSize;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    //pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    sem_init(&empty,0,BufferSize);
    sem_init(&full,0,0);

    pid_t id1, id2;

    id1 = fork();
    if (id1 == 0) {
      
        id2 = fork();
        if (id2 == 0) //child 2
        {
            printf("im the consumer");
            consumer();
        }else{ //child 1
            printf("i'm the producer");
            producer();
        }
    }else{
        sem_destroy(&full);
        sem_destroy(&empty);
        //pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

thank you so much

Comment: Small detail, in your current code you spawn 2 processes (3 total), but the original one is destroying the semaphores immediately after `fork`, so the new processes will likely spawn with destroyed semaphores.

Comment: True i just fixed that and put a wait function in the main process. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, different processes live in different virtual address spaces. They cannot access each other's memory. The same is true for POSIX semaphores. This means that when you use `fork` to make two processes, you end up with two different sets of variables. You have a separate `buffer` and semaphores for each process.

To make this work, you should create a memory mapping (`mmap` for POSIX) where you put all the data you need to share between the processes, including the semaphores. The semaphores should be initialized with `pshared` to non-zero. The man page for `sem_init` has more details about this.

Alternatively you could use some other form of inter-process communication, like pipes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, now I have a clear vision of what's happening. yes I'm going to make another version with pipes too. now it should work when I share the buffer between the processes, thanks @elderBug